# spring boot validator success but no exception throw

Tags: validation, exception, spring-boot

I use validator in my spring boot, but can not catch any exception, my code is like that

first I create a bean with annotation

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class OrderDetailPO extends BaseEntity<String>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max=32,message="ordercode is null")
    private String orderCode;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max=32,message="productMode is null")
    private String productMode;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max=128,message="hotelType is null")
    private String hotelType;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max=32,message="goodsId is null")
    private String goodsId;
}
```

then I use @validated in the controller

```
public Result<?> createOrderDetail( @RequestBody @Validated  OrderDetailPO orderDetail,BindingResult bindingResult) throws ParseException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

//       if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {  
//              String errMsg="";
//              for(FieldError err: bindingResult.getFieldErrors()) {  
//                  errMsg += err.getField()+" is " + err.getCode();
//              }  
//              return Result.buildFail(errMsg);
//          }
```

then I use an empty request send to the controller, but nothing happens... 
In my opinion, I can see the error in bindingResult,  but I can not catch an exception as MethodArgumentNotValidException even if I delete bindingResult , and how can I let the exception appear?

yeah, if I only have param not requestbody, how to throw exception? for example

```
 public Result<?> orderDetailSelByAccountId( @NotBlank @Size(min=10,max=32)@PathVariable(value="accountId") String accountId) {
}
```

Comment: So didn't you get 400 (Bad Request) for empty request after invoking the service?

Comment: you should throw it by your own. If `if (bindingResult.hasErrors())` is true you can throw your exception

Comment: @LHCHIN no ,nothing happaned : （

Comment: @Patrick  I found in web someone said that  the method can throw itself, so , if I have only one param, for example,at NotNull at requestvariable String id. in this case can not use bindingresults, how can I catch the exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `@Valid` annotation on your `OrderDetailPO` you have some options to handle an invalid request.

**Option 1:**

You use `BindingResult` in your method signature like you did in your code. Now you are able to use `if (bindingResult.hasErrors())` and if it is true you are free to do anything you want. You can throw your own exceptions, return a custom message or just go on with your code. Thats your decision. And you don't have to catch any exception.

**Option 2:**

Delete `BindingResult` in your method signature. This means that Spring will automatically return a `BadRequest` to the client. It will respond with an `org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException` with all the information about the invalid request. In this case you will not enter your method. Same as option 1, no exception must be caught.

Comment: yeah, thks! I delete the bindingResut and the exception finally appeared. So  I can use the exception catch centre to catch the exceptions. thank you

Comment: public Result<?> orderDetailSelByAccountId( @NotBlank @Size(min=10,max=32)@PathVariable(value="accountId") String accountId) {

Comment: Thanks for this! I had an Errors object and that was stopping Spring from throwing an exception automatically. Taking it out fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
 @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
```

you will find an example here : https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-adding-validation-to-a-rest-api/

Comment: ExceptionHandler is to handle the exception, but the exception don't  even appear in the system

Comment: For the exception to appear, you can remove BindingResult  from your method signature. Spring will handle the validation failure by throwing a MethodArgumentNotValidException that will be handled as BadRequest if you don't provid an ExceptionHandler to that exception.